# slide menu locations and icon

Tags: usability, icons, menu, mobile-web

what is the best location on the side slide menu?

and lets say the app is localized to many different languages and its web app responsive to mobile , is it better to shift is place in each language? "i.e. Arabic on the right, English on the left"
 and am having problem deciding whether we should place the icon inside the menu or just the app logo.

Answer (score 2):

If the menu is the master section of a master-detail pattern, it should probably be on the left in English and adjusted to the right in RTL languages. 
This is because if follows the direction of reading and the hierarchy people are used to in that locale.

Besides, putting RTL text in a menu that slides from the left is a bit weird... would you align it left or right?

Not sure I understand your question about the icon.

Comment: thank you, and you have a point about RTL languages, the icon issue that is I see the header of the slide menu is empty and dull, i was asking is it ok to place the app logo in it's header? or just stick to the slide menu icon?

Comment: If you put app logo on the side menu's header, what will happen when the menu is hidden? The app logo should not be hidden along with slider.